# MUI 4 custom Button color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i'm using mui V4 for my styling i'm trying to add an additional color for my buttons, I know that it does only accept these

```
expected one of ["default","inherit","primary","secondary"].
```

I'm using a palette to get things done
[palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l14VY.png)
so is there a simple way to override that and add my custom color?

Comment: Is this the error you receive? Are you using Typescript? if so, you need to extend the module definition https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Comment: thnx for the reply no I'm using js, and its related to muiV4 cause in v5 I can use the error color I can't do that in muiV4 , I'm only allowed to use primary or secondary

Answer (score 0):

here in [v4 documentation](https://v4.mui.com/customization/palette/) it explains you can both override error and add custom colors

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  status: {
    danger: '#e53e3e',
  },
  palette: {
    neutral: {
      main: '#5c6ac4',
    },
  },
});
```

> You may override the default palette values by including a palette
> object as part of your theme. If any of the:
>
> palette.primary palette.secondary palette.error palette.warning
> palette.info palette.success palette color objects are provided, they
> will replace the defaults.